# Destroying Keys With Rotation

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I have a bunch of keys in a keyring that I want to destroy (essentially "cleaning-up" the keyring. I've currently written a script that (using gcloud cli):

- will iterate through all the keys
- grab all versions for each key
- destroy each version

1. Is there a better way to go about this? A bulk destroy of all versions at once for a particular key for example?
2. These keys are configured with a scheduled auto-rotation. If I schedule all the versions for destruction but the next rotation period is before the key version is destroyed, will it still rotate? Do I also have to disable key rotation on all these keys to really prevent them from coming back??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct.

1. Yes, this is the best way. You can parallelize the deletion operations to make it go faster.
2. Deleting key versions does not disable the rotation policy. You must disable key rotation policies to prevent new key versions from being created.